# Best way to Visualise Windows Icons on Form?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, icons

### Background

I want to drag "icons" from the desktop on to my form, they will then be visualised on the form, not changing in appearance.

When i say "icon", i mean shortcuts, folders and application icons.

**Example**

[image]

### Question

What is the best way of recreating the icons on the form. Is there a tried and tested way, or do you have to recreated them using picture
boxes and labels?

### What I've Tried so Far?

- Picture boxes
- Forms

I've had limited success with both, with the latter being the best so far. However both have their limitations.

**Notes.**

I do not need help with other areas of my problem like, how to drag icons, extracting icons, etc. It's purely just recreating the icon visually i'm struggling with.

Comment: Mind using WPF? WinForms is not the best for doing these sort of things

Comment: @Farnan Anan, Sorry,I have absolutely no experience with WPF.

Comment: What about using a ListView?

Comment: I think i would like to stay on the track of the icon appearing as if it has seamlessly moved from the desktop to the form, and then dropped into my application. A list view would change the aesthetics a little.

Comment: What is the problem with using PictureBoxes? Performance?

Comment: I couldn't get the text part of the icon to display properly using its paint event. I need more control over the text. I've moved on to using a form, however forms aren't inherently transparent. Which has lead me to ask if there is a better way.

Comment: You are only focusing on the way it looks but don't seem to have much an idea of what these icons actually represent.  There are hundreds of megabytes of gritty compiled C++ code behind it that you cannot easily see.  Explorer is a very non-trivial chunk of code.  Just that tiny little arrow in the lower left corner takes a lot of glue to display the correct overlay icon and allow an application to select a custom one and change it.  Replacing Explorer is the kind of project that is only ever started but never finished.

Comment: I completely agree. I only want to emulate a small part. I already have the logic and functionality required for my project. I just need to crack the front end with regards to how it looks.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `ListView` and set the view property to `LargeIcon`.

You can obtain the icons through: Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon.  However, you may need to manage the icons as two files with the same extension may have different icons.

If you only want the image, then you can grab just the icon portion of the control after it's painted.